# Creating a new column based on three existing columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame with three columns, `target_degrees`, `low_degrees`, and `high_degrees`. I would like to make a new column labeled success that checks to see if target_degrees is located between `low_degrees` and `high_degrees`.

example dataframe:

```
target_degrees   low_degrees   high_degrees   success
   10                0              50          1
   50                45             100         1
   20               100             200         0
   1                300             350         0
```

I have tried using `np.where` in the following code but I am getting a syntax error.

```
df['success'] = np.where(df['target_degrees'] is in np.arange(df['low_degrees'], df['high_degrees']), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple conditions:

```
df['success'] = np.where(((df['target_degrees'] >= df['low_degrees']) & (df['target_degrees']<= df['high_degrees'])), 1, 0)
```

**output**:

```
  target_degrees  low_degrees   high_degrees    success
0       10                 0         50            1
1       50                45        100            1
2       20               100        200            0
3        1               300        350            0
```

Comment: You don't need `numpy.where` for binary conditions, you can just cast to `int` to avoid the overhead

Answer (score 0):

A bit more concisely with [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) method:

```
df['success'] = df['target_degrees'].between(df['low_degrees'], df['high_degrees'])
```